# Get image link from child element

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm new with colorbox, and so far everything looks fine but i would like to get `href` from child element. So let's say i have `div` and `a` inside of that div:

```
<div id="colorbox">
   <a id="image" href="image.jpg">img</a>
</div>
```

And now i'm using basic function:

```
$("#colorbox").colorbox();
```

So ofc it won't work so iv'e tried to do it like this:

```
$("#colorbox").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#image"});
```

And it only messed everything up, how else can i get path to my image?

Btw in my page it's going to be a lot of `div` with images all of them going to have same `id`

Comment: 1. All of them *can't* have the same `id`. It's invalid markup. Make it a `class` instead.

Comment: IDs should be unique. You shouldn't give them the same ID as it means your jQuery selectors will just use the first element it finds each time I believe

Comment: You can't have many elements with the same ID.  It's invalid and results in weird problems.

Comment: 'all of them going to have same id' - this is invalid html!

Comment: I didn't knew that id have to be unique thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not have multiple samples a `tag` with the same `id`, id's should be unique, you can use class instead if your elements must have the same identifier.

From your code sample, you can get the href value like this

```
var imgHref = $('#colorbox').find('a#image').attr('href');
```

there are many ways to get it though.